# ImportError: <PKG_NAME> not found in importing a Julia package in Python using PyJulia

Tags: python, julia, pyjulia

I tried to import a registered Julia package into Python to use it but I got an error (I followed [this turorial](https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/how-to-call-julia-code-from-python-8589a56a98f2)):

```
$ pip install julia
```

```py
>>> import julia
>>> julia.install()
...
Precompiling PyCall...
Precompiling PyCall... DONE
PyCall is installed and built successfully.
```

After a complete installation, I tried to install the required package:

```py
>>> from julia import Main as jl
>>> from julia import Pkg
>>> Pkg.add("OnlinePortfolioSelection")
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.9\Manifest.toml`
>>> Pkg.status()
Status `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v1.3.2
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.10.11
  [aaaa29a8] Clustering v0.15.2 `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\dev\Clustering`
  [a2441757] Coverage v1.6.0
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.6.1
  [aaf54ef3] DistributedArrays v0.6.7
  [cd3eb016] HTTP v1.10.0
  [358108f5] JMcDM v0.7.8 `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\dev\JMcDM`
  [dc48124f] LinearSegmentation v0.2.0 `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\dev\LinearSegmentation`
  [5fb14364] OhMyREPL v0.5.22
  [038f9fe3] OnlinePortfolioSelection v1.8.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.39.0
  [aea7be01] PrecompileTools v1.2.0
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.96.1
  [295af30f] Revise v3.5.6
  [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.34.2
  [e4b3b0a2] YFinance v0.1.4
```

All good, then I tried to import the package:

```py
>>> from julia import OnlinePortfolioSelection as OPS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Shayan\miniconda3\envs\im\lib\site-packages\julia\core.py", line 260, in load_module
    raise ImportError("{} not found".format(juliapath))
ImportError: OnlinePortfolioSelection not found
```

Where's the problem?

**Update1:**
I can import `DataFrames` package, so the problem is related to the `OnlinePortfolioSelection` package. But, I don't know what's the problem.

**Update2:**
I think there is a problem with finding the path to Julia as we have `raise ImportError("{} not found".format(juliapath))` within the error message. So, I decided to remove Julia from the path and run the codes to get the error again. Then I closed the Python session and added Julia's path to the environment variables, and rerun Python. This time, the package was loaded successfully. I don't know where should I report this problem.

Comment: 1. I am not sure where `juliapath` is taken from but you could try to set up `JULIA_HOME`, and `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` system variables and than rerun `julia.install()`  (You might for an example have more than one Julia on your machine). 2. Consider using PythonCall & JuliaCall instead. From my experience the `julia` Python module often creates installation issues and `juliacall` might be a better alternative.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, Thank you! Yes, I'm aware of `juliacall`. But I wanted to try `PyJulia` as well. Surely I consider your recommendations, and hopefully, this issue will be solved. Thank you so much.